# Coffeescript . for/in loop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Anybody knows if it is possible to get a

**javascript for/in loop**

from coffeescript?

Actually would like to write the js function

```
function logobject(o) {
   for (p in o)
     console.log(p + "=" + o[p])
}
```

in coffeescript.

Comment: Not a `coffee-script` programmer, but shouldn't it work just as it is?

Comment: No, coffeescript has other loops that it converts to js loops. usually in a convenient way.

Comment: Then +1, I would like to hear the answer as well... `:)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
console.log "#{k}=#{v}" for k, v of o
```

Answer (score 28):

This might be a bit confusing for CoffeeScript newbies, but the `for..in` loop is used to iterate over arrays, while the `for..of` loop is used to iterate over objects.

```
logobject = (o) ->
  console.log key + "=" + value for key, value of o
```

Also, to restrict this to own properties of the object (skips inherited properties via hasOwnProperty()), the "own" keyword can be added:

```
for own key, value of o
```

Comment: right, and now i even find it in the dense docu, thx a lot, both helpful

Comment: That is kind of crazy since js is kind of the opposite. [For...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is for objects and [For...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is for arrays (iterables)